# Responsive email signature doesn't work on iPhone

Tags: html, ios, html-email

I made a layout with tables. Design is 2 columns in the first row and 3 on the second. When screen is below 600px width `<td>` wraps because i made it inline-block.
And the problem is everything works well on the web, android, mac but ios devices has layout like on desktops

code: https://jsfiddle.net/jcp2hz7v/1/
links are broken intentionally.

Comment: Please post your code, otherwise we can only point to general answers easily found on Google

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is add a `@media` query so that below 600px the relevant `<td>`s are set to max-width:100%. That way, they will cover the whole line. As it is, they only move to the next line when they run out of space - and some iPhones are very large!

Add this to the head (this works on mobiles, excepting only Gmail IMAP):

```
<style type="text/css">
  @media screen and (max-width:600px) {
    td.mobile {max-width:100%!important;}
  }
</style>
```

Add the 'mobile' class to the second row of `<td>`s

Your code is not working well on Outlook either, which does not respect `max-width`. You'll need a wrapper to ensure it stays at 600px, i.e.

```
<!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
<table width="600" align="center" style="border-collapse:collapse;mso-table-lspace:0pt;mso-table-rspace:0pt;border-spacing:0;font-family:Arial, sans-serif;color:#333333;" >
<tr>
<td style="padding-top:0;padding-bottom:0;padding-right:0;padding-left:0;border-collapse:collapse;" >
<![endif]-->
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" style="max-width: 600px; min-width: 230px; width: 100%">
...
</table>
 <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: Thanx but this signature goes to google client which removes any <style> and comments